# Website horribly slow to load. (Around 15 seconds)

Tags: magento-1.9, websites

I have all cache enabled, running around 16GBs of memory, 8 core CPU. And yet, the website is still horribly slow. Fetching the products takes around 15 seconds or so! Trying to see what's taking so long, I found that products.html is what's taking so long.

The odd thing is, if I call the -entire- product collection from my own code, it takes around 1-2 seconds. But on the website it's taking well over 15 seconds!

What might be causing this slow down? And how can I solve the issue?

[image]

Comment: Have you checked your code?

Comment: @Pat,
Its really happining with every product listing site If you can show me some example of code then I will help you other wise you have one option for this you can check this website which is full of product listing and you can modify according to this. [Click here](http://www.voylla.com/jewellery) you can get Idea of this if you won't get Idea then let me know

Answer (score 0):

Usually I start my performance analysis from install newrelic agent on server. After install go to traces and look at transactions. @Pat right, mostly problem is load every product in list, or load every category for count in menu. You should trace your code for more details.

Comment: I'm using the Porto theme. I haven't done any modifications to the website. My own code is actually running much faster, but I don't want to replace the website with it.

Comment: U should find part of source code which generate multiple sql requests and   replace that. For example if u find foreach with product->load() u should remove it and add missing product fields in your collection when collection loaded.